# Code to save image in sql database in smartface.io

Tags: smartface.io

Hello Smartface community,

Please assist with me an important step in application of saving image in the database in binary format into sql database and retrieve it.

```
function testPage_Image1_OnTouch(e) {
  //  alert("Image is pressed");

    Device.Media.pickFromGallery({
        type : [SMF.MediaType.image, SMF.MediaType.movie, SMF.MediaType.sound],
        onSuccess : function (e) {

            //alert("we are here");

            Pages.testPage.Image1.image = e.file;


            SMF.Image.prototype.getBlob();

            var img = new SMF.Image(e.image);
            //alert("img : "+ img);
            var blob = new Blob(img);
            //alert("blob : " + blob);
            var base64StringDataForRegisterImage = blob.toBase64String();
            //alert("base64StringDataForRegisterImage : " + base64StringDataForRegisterImage);


            //InsertImgData(base64StringDataForRegisterImage);

        },
        onCancel : function (e) {
            alert("cancelled");
        },
        onError : function (e) {
            alert("failed");
        }
    });
}
```

When I run this code which is given on the smartface page, throws error for below line as "undefined is not a function (evaluating SMF.Image.prototype.getBlob()');

```
SMF.Image.prototype.getBlob();
```

Please assist with correct code if I am missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: SMF.Image doesn't support getBlob() by default . This code line breaks your code.

Comment: I got the code from smartface web site, Do you have any other method to achive the same